# How to Join two collections in MongoDB and NodeJS with $lookup and DbRef?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, dbref

If i have two collections where one of that have dbref, how is possibile to join using $lookup and dbref?

Comment: Basically, No. `$lookup` relies on "matching a field" in the other collection. So if one field is of BSON type `DBref` and the other is of `ObjectId` then the two "types" are not the same, and therefore will not match. As a related issue `$lookup` cannot use data in the `DBRef` such as the "collection", and you need to specify manually. So instead of `DBRef` you "should" use a regular `ObjectId` value. One more reason why `DBRef` is "evil". Don't use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo how to $lookup with DBRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622714/mongo-how-to-lookup-with-dbref)

Answer (score 0):

DBref is a BSON Object and you cannot make a lookup using its value.

BUT, there is a way to do it, transforming a DBRef object into an array.
[I have written an answer a few months ago describing how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622714/mongo-how-to-lookup-with-dbref/46240372#46240372)

### Short explanation

Say you have DBRef object like this :

```
myField: DBRef("otherCollection", ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")),
```

Use $objectToArray on myField like this

```
db.myColl.aggregate([
    {
        $project: { 
            transformedDBRef: {$objectToArray: "$myField"},                
            }    
    },    
])
```

The result would be an array of two objects, one object for the reference, one for the ObjectId contained within the DBRef, each with a field "k" and a field "v". It will look like this:

```
transformedDBRef: [{"k" : "$ref","v" : "otherCollection"},{"k" : "$id","v" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")}
```

You can then grep the ObjectId. For the complete solution, please check the link above.