# Mongo how to $lookup with DBRef

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a trouble(/(ㄒoㄒ)/~~). Suppose that collection A is

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"), 
    "bid" : [
        DBRef("B", ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")),
        DBRef("B", ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"))
    ]
}
```

and Collection B:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0"),  
    "status" : NumberInt(1), 
    "seq" : NumberInt(0)
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"), 
    "status" : NumberInt(1), 
    "seq" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

I don't know how to $lookup the 'bid'. I tried

```
db.A.aggregate(
    [
        {$unwind: {path: "$bid"}},
        {$lookup: {from: "B", localField: "bid", foreignField: "_id", as: "bs"}},
    ]
)
```

and

```
db.A.aggregate(
    [
        {$unwind: {path: "$bid"}},
        {$lookup: {from: "B", localField: "bid.$id", foreignField: "_id", as: "bs"}},
    ]
)
```

but it doesn't work. Anybody can help?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a real reason for using `DBRef` in your docs? from the docs: `Unless you have a compelling reason to use DBRefs, use manual references instead` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/)

Answer (score 33):

Actually, the other answer is wrong. It is possible to do a lookup on a DBref field within your aggregator, and you don't need mapreduce for that.

### Solution

```
db.A.aggregate([
{
    $project: { 
        B_fk: {
          $map: { 
             input: { 
                  $map: {
                      input:"$bid",
                      in: {
                           $arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray: "$$this"}, 1]
                      },
                  }
             },
             in: "$$this.v"}},
        }
}, 
{
    $lookup: {
        from:"B", 
        localField:"B_fk",
        foreignField:"_id", 
        as:"B"
    }
}
])
```

result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59bb79df1e9c00162566f581"),
    "B_fk" : null,
    "B" : [ ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
    "B_fk" : [
        ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0"),
        ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1")
    ],
    "B" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0"),
            "status" : NumberInt("1"),
            "seq" : NumberInt("0")
        }
    ]
}
```

### Short Explanation

Loop through the DBRefs with $map, break each DBref into an array, keep only the $id field, then get rid of the k:v format with $$this.v, keeping only the ObjectId and removing all the rest. You can now lookup on the ObjectId.

### Step-by-step Explanation

Within the aggregator, a DBRef BSON type can be handled like an object, with two or three fields (ref, id, and db).

If you do:

```
db.A.aggregate([
    {
        $project: { 
            First_DBref_as_array: {$objectToArray:{$arrayElemAt:["$bid",0]}},
            Second_DBref_as_array: {$objectToArray:{$arrayElemAt:["$bid",1]}},
            }

    },

])
```

This is the result:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
"First_DBref_as_array : [
    {
        "k" : "$ref",
        "v" : "B"
    },
    {
        "k" : "$id",
        "v" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")
    }
],
"Second_DBref_as_array" : [
    {
        "k" : "$ref",
        "v" : "B"
    },
    {
        "k" : "$id",
        "v" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")
    }
]
}
```

Once you have transformed a dbref into an array, you can get rid of the useless fields by querying only the value at index 1, like this:

```
db.A.aggregate([
    {
        $project: { 
            First_DBref_as_array: {$arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray:{$arrayElemAt:["$bid",0]}},1]},
            Second_DBref_as_array: {$arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray:{$arrayElemAt:["$bid",0]}},1]},
            }

    },

])
```

result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
    "First_DBref_as_array" : {
        "k" : "$id",
        "v" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")
    },
    "Second_DBref_as_array" : {
        "k" : "$id",
        "v" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")
    }
}
```

Then you can get finally to the value you want by pointing to "$myvalue.v", just like this

```
db.A.aggregate([
    {
        $project: { 
            first_DBref_as_array: {$arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray:{$arrayElemAt:["$bid",0]}},1]},
            second_DBref_as_array: {$arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray:{$arrayElemAt:["$bid",0]}},1]},
            }

    },
    {
        $project: {
            first_DBref_as_ObjectId: "$first_DBref_as_array.v",
            second_DBref_as_ObjectId: "$second_DBref_as_array.v"
        }
    }

])
```

result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
    "first_DBref_as_ObjectId" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0"),
    "second_DBref_as_ObjectId" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")
}
```

Obviously, in a normal pipeline, you don't need all these redundant steps, using a nested $map, you can get to the same result in one go :

```
db.A.aggregate([
    {
        $project: { 
            B_fk: { $map : {input: { $map: {    input:"$bid",
                                    in: { $arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray: "$$this"}, 1 ]}, } },
                            in: "$$this.v"}},

            }
    }, 

])
```

result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
    "B_fk" : [
        ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0"),
        ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1")
    ]
}
```

I hope the explanation is clear enough, if not feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this part "then get rid of the k:v format with $$this.v, keeping only the ObjectId and removing all the rest." ?

Comment: As I have detailed in the second part of the answer, once you transform a DBref into an array, it will look like this : 
`[{"k" : "$ref","v" : "B"},{"k" : "$id","v" : ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")}`. Since you want only the objectId, you need to refer to it with $$this.v instead of just $$this inside the $map operation

Comment: @OlivierMaurel Can you provide the same in solution in spring mongo? I can seem to understand how to convert the same to spring boot Mongodb. Instead of ObjectID, I need to lookup the actual fields associated with the ref and id.

Answer (score 11):

Just in case someone is coming here in 2021:

Starting with MongoDB 4.3.3 the second query of the OP does work:

```
db.A.aggregate(
    [
        {$unwind: {path: "$bid"}},
        {$lookup: {from: "B", localField: "bid.$id", foreignField: "_id", as: "bs"}},
    ]
)
```

The result is:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
   "bid":DBRef("B", "ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")),
   "bs":[
      {
         "_id":ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0")",
         "status":1,
         "seq":0
      }
   ]
}{
   "_id":ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
   "bid":DBRef("B", "ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1")),
   "bs":[
      {
         "_id":ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
         "status":1,
         "seq":0
      }
   ]
}
```

See [SERVER-14466](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14466) for more information.

Answer (score 8):

As of mongoDB 3.4, **this is not possible**. You can't use DBRef in the aggregation pipeline, except in the [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage.

I strongly recommend you to get rid of DBRef and switch to manual references. However, if you really need to keep DBRef, here is an (ugly) solution:

first, create a new collection named "C", where DBRefs are replaced by their Ids using mapReduce:

```
db.A.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var key = this._id; 
        var value = [];  
        for ( var index = 0; index < this.bid.length; index++){
           value.push(this.bid[index].$id); 
        }
        emit(key, value); 
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return  values;
    },
    {
        "query": {},
        "out": "C" 
    }
)
```

then, run your aggregation query on the new "C" collection:

```
db.C.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind:"$value"
   },
   {
      $lookup:{
         from:"B",
         localField:"value",
         foreignField:"_id",
         as:"bs"
      }
   }
]);
```

output:

```
    {
       "_id":ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
       "value":ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0"),
       "bs":[
          {
             "_id":ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e0"),
             "status":1,
             "seq":0
          }
       ]
    }{
       "_id":ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
       "value":ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
       "bs":[
          {
             "_id":ObjectId("582abcd85d2dfa67f44127e1"),
             "status":1,
             "seq":0
          }
       ]
    }
```