# MongoDB $lookup query returning empty field

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

There are two collections in my database, `Projects` and `Tasks`. Each project can have a number of tasks associated to it. I am trying to create a MongoDB query in Java that will return a `Task` and also embed the `Project` that is linked to it, however the code I have completed so far only returns an empty array (I have named this `something` which appears as `[]` below).

Unfortunately I have not found many examples on how to properly use `$lookup` in Java. What changes do I need to perform on the code so the `something` field comes back with a `project`? Should I be using `$lookup` or another aggregation operator?

**The Java method I am using with mongo-java-driver version 3.5.0:**

```
public static String readTask()
{
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("exampleDatabase");

    Bson lookup = new Document("$lookup",
            new Document("from", "Project")
                    .append("localField", "project._id")
                    .append("foreignField", "_id")
                    .append("as", "something"));

    List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add(lookup);

    AggregateIterable<Document> it = database.getCollection("Task").aggregate(filters);
    System.out.println("First Document: " + it.first().toString());

    return it.first().toString();
}
```

**This method currently returns the following:**

```
{
    _id = 599a62cac29d9a2684c64012,
    constructionRoomNumber = 15,
    type = Example,
    summary = Summary Text,
    description = Description Text,
    status = Open,
    project = {
        "$ref": "Project",
        "$id": "5996582a0983347784fb2ff4"
    },
    something = []
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('599a62cac29d9a2684c64012')
    constructionRoomNumber: "15"
    type: "Example"
    summary: "Summary Text"
    description: "Description Text"
    status: "Open"
    project: {
        _id: ObjectId('5996582a0983347784fb2ff4')
        projectCode: "V1000"
        projectName: "Example Project"
        projectLocation: "1 Somewhere Street, Some City"
        clientName: "Whatever Client"
        isActive: true
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what the data stored in MongoDB looks like:

**Example Project:**

```
_id: ObjectId('5996582a0983347784fb2ff4')
projectCode: "V1000"
projectName: "Example Project"
projectLocation: "1 Somewhere Street, Some City"
clientName: "Whatever Client"
isActive: true
```

**Example Task:**

```
_id: ObjectId('599a62cac29d9a2684c64012')
constructionRoomNumber: "15"
type: "Example"
summary: "Summary Text"
description: "Description Text"
status: "Open"
project: DBRef(Project, 5996582a0983347784fb2ff4, undefined)
```

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41677055/7717350 DBRef doesn't supported in the `$lookup` phase.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate, as there is way to get ObjectIds from DBRefs objects,see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying a lookup on a DBRef field, which is not supported.

However, there is  a [workaround to transform DBRefs into simple ObjectId that I have detailed on a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46240372/7495147), you can adapt it in Java or use it in a native query.