# How to do join in mongodb with database references

Tags: mongodb

My mongo database has two collections (samples copied from MongoDB query result):

```
Order: 
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f242e68ceebdd59a456fee5"),
"date": ISODate("2020-07-30T22:00:00.000Z"),
"user" : {
        "$ref" : "user",
        "$id" : "user_0"
},
"item": "banana"
}

User:
{
    "_id" : "user_0",
    "login" : "login_0",
    "password" : "$2a$10$mE.qmcV0mFU5NcKh73TZx.z4ueI/.bDWbj0T1BYyqP481kGGarKLG",
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" : "Kennedy",
    "email" : "jfk@gmail.com",
    "activated" : true
}
```

Each order belongs to a user. I put inside every Order's object a collection reference of the corresponding user.

With MongoDB's aggregation function, how would you do to get the number of Order that belongs to a user and put it inside an object alongside with his first name and his last name? I want a result to look somehow like this:

```
TopUser 
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Kennedy",
    "nbOfOrders": 3
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "orders",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "user.id",
      "as": "users"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
        _id:0,
      first_name: 1,
      last_name: 1,
      nbOfOrders: {
        $size: "$users"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LF_uZL5NXAD)
Note: Remove `$` from `$ref` and `$id`

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a question though. What does the value 1 of the field "first_name" really mean and where is it documented?

Comment: 1 - to include the field, 0-to exclue the field. Refer this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: I just tested it today, but it didn't work for me, the "$users" array contains actually nothing although it's supposed to have all the orders that the user made (just like in mongodb playground)

Comment: The relationship between two tables is userId, no? I made the aggregation pipeline based on how you given the data, and I posted a Demo also, If you feel you can add more details, please edit

Comment: Yes, I just checked it. It's user. Inside the java class Order, I have             
    @DBRef
    @Field("user")
    private User user; this creates a one to one association between 2 collections: User and Order

Comment: Ok, what's the issue now ur facing?

Comment: Well, I tested your function and it gave me {
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" : "Kennedy",
    "nbOfOrder" : 0
}. Although, I'm pretty sure that this user makes a lot of orders. The same thing happended to all users.

Comment: Haha, it seems funny. You have given your sample data, what @varman did was correct for the question, you have to try your own with given answer, We can't predict what your database has, or you should have posted all the relevant information

Comment: hello, how would you guys do it with the pipeline of the lookup function?

Comment: The question is regarding mkngodb, right? Not spring?

Comment: yep, it's all about mongodb, I think I found a reason why it doesn't work. That's because I used DBRef inside order. I also think that the answer it's in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622714/mongo-how-to-lookup-with-dbref

Comment: I have no idea to continue this question. The answer is provided based on your question, but you ask something else. If the question mentioned spring boot, i could have given a solution to that. Anyhow, keep it up.

Comment: Just curious, coming from RDBM world, do you need to create some kind of index or table structured information when we want to do efficient joins like these? or it will still work (albeit less performant)

Comment: @stanley_manley If you have large scale data, you must. Sorry for late reply