# How to create advanced aggregation with lookup and filtering in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I need to create advanced aggregation using Spring Data MongoDB having model like that:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document
public class Library {

  @Id
  @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
  private ObjectId id;

  private Address address;

  private String workingHours;

  ...

}

@Getter
@Setter
@Document
public class Book {

  @Id
  @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
  private ObjectId id;

  private Boolean published;

  private Boolean hidden;

  private String title;

  @DBRef
  @NotNull
  private Library library;

  ...

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Libraries collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697"), 
    "workingHours" : "8:00 PM - 8:00 AM",
    "address" : DBRef("addresses", ObjectId("5f4544198da452a5523e3d11"))
}
```

Books collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f454423be823729015661ed"), 
    "published": true,
    "hidden": false,
    "title": "The Hobbit, or There and Back Again"
    "library" : DBRef("libraries", ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697"))
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f45445b876d08649b88ed5a"), 
    "published": true,
    "hidden": false,
    "title": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone"
    "library" : DBRef("libraries", ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697"))
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f45446c7e33ca70363f629a"), 
    "published": true,
    "hidden": false,
    "title": "Harry Potter and the Cursed Child"
    "library" : DBRef("libraries", ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697"))
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f45447285f9b3e4cb8739ad"), 
    "published": true,
    "hidden": false,
    "title": "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them"
    "library" : DBRef("libraries", ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697"))
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f45449fc121a20afa4fbb96"), 
    "published": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "title": "Universal Parks & Resorts"
    "library" : DBRef("libraries", ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697"))
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4544a5f13839bbe89edb23"), 
    "published": false,
    "hidden": true,
    "title": "Ministry of Dawn"
    "library" : DBRef("libraries", ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697"))
}
```

**Features:**

1. User must be able to filter by each field. -> That's not the problem for me. Based on passed parameters I would create `Criteria` and use `Aggregation.match()`.
2. Depending on the context of the user, I have to return a different count of books that can be filtered based on `startsWith()` or `like()` principle. -> Here I have a problem.

Assuming that I have 4 published books, one more added by normal user and one more hidden.

1. Administrator should know about all of them, so he will see `booksCount` as `6`.
2. The regular user sees only published or added by himself, so he will see `booksCount` as `5`.
3. Not logged users see only published, so he will see `booksCount` as `4`.
4. There can be some other conditions in the future.

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").ne(null).and("address.city").is("Chicago");

if (!isAdministrator()) {
    criteria = criteria.and("published").is(Boolean.TRUE);
}

MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(criteria);

LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().from("books").localField("id").foreignField("library.$id").as("books");

UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("books");
CountOperation countOperation = Aggregation.count().as("booksCount");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, lookupOperation, unwindOperation, countOperation);

mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "libraries", Document.class).getRawResults().getInteger("booksCount");
```

At first I thought I would use `LookupOperation`, but it doesn't work properly (it fetches all books in the collection independently from `ObjectId`). Unfortunately, I ran into a problem that we can't use `DBRef` in the aggregation pipeline, except in the `$match` stage. [Here is the description of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41677055/7801072).

I read the explanation in the second post, but I don't know how to implement such advanced projection with map operation using Spring Data MongoDB. Additionally, I would like to be able to filter by this value as described in the second point.

My questions are:

1. How can I achieve such behavior using Spring Data MongoDB (I'll probably be able to tweak the version a little bit)?
2. If we implement this, will I be able to apply appropriate filters to `booksCount` as stated in description?
3. Is there another way to accomplish such behavior using another library, framework or functionality? I was thinking only about custom DTO, querying all existing libraries, looping through them and based on passed parameters query `booksCount`. But that won't solve the filtering and pagination problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I also strongly recommend not to use @DBRef since it jas implications like slowing down. If you het rid of dbref, the process you need to achive is so easy using aggregation pipelines

Comment: You can even use `$text` search with mathc stage as you mentioned above